# Use VBA to tell Outlook to print to a specific printer

Tags: vba, printing, outlook

Is there any way to write a VBA macro in Outlook that forces a printout to a specific printer (even if it's not necessarily the default printer), similar to the Word

```
Application.ActivePrinter = "Printer Name"
```

option? I'd like to create a button that prints the current email and attachments to a specific printer (in this case a PDF printer, but I'm guessing it should be the same principle regardless), but can't seem to find a way to force which printer is used in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Outlook only exposes `MailItem.PrintOut` method.

You can save the message in the DOC or RTF format using MailItem.SaveAs, open it in Word, and use the Word Object Model to print it.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. My goal was to send to a PDF printer; using your solution I was able to save as a PDF in Word. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This was the first thing that came up while searching recently for how to print to a PDF from Outlook, so this is pretty much an FYI for a simpler method noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70346591/mailitem-printout-to-pdf).

Add the Word COM reference to your project and do this:

```
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document, MyMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set WordDoc = MyMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
WordDoc.SaveAs2 TempPDF, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
    Dim WshNetwork As Object
    Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    WshNetwork.setDefaultPrinter "Microsoft Print to PDF"
```

Fill the string with your printer name.