# How to set the default printer using VBA in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

In Excel I'm able to set the default printer using for example:

```
Application.ActivePrinter = "My Printer on Ne03:"
```

and I can confirm it got set by `MsgBox Application.ActivePrinter`

The same code doesn't work in Outlook's VBA. I get

> Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

Update:
I have now referenced the Excel application to get access to its Application object as shown below:

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim excelapp as Object
    
    excelapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
    MsgBox excelapp.ActivePrinter
    excelapp.ActivePrinter = "My Printer on Ne03:" 
    
End Sub
```

I got a

> Run-time error 1004 Unable to set the ActivePrinter property of the Application class

for `excelapp.ActivePrinter = "My Printer on Ne03:"`.

I ensured the macro settings in Excel are all enabled and printer name is correct. However `MsgBox excelapp.ActivePrinter` works fine.

Comment: Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method. The Outlook Application Object doesn't support `.ActivePrinter`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use VBA to tell Outlook to print to a specific printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474072/use-vba-to-tell-outlook-to-print-to-a-specific-printer)

Comment: @niton Thanks. I've tried referencing the excel application using `excelapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` then tried setting the printer using `excelapp.ActivePrinter = "My Printer on Ne03:"` I got a `Run-time error 1004 Unable to set the ActivePrinter property of the Application class` I have ensured the macro settings in excel are all enabled. However `MsgBox excelapp.ActivePrinter` works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Edit the question with the additional information in your comment and include [mcve].

Comment: It seems to work only if you use 
Set excelapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")