# Mailitem.PrintOut() to PDF

Tags: vba, pdf, printing, outlook

I want to print a complete email to pdf.

The standard printer is selected as Microsoft Print to PDF.

Running the printout method, a SaveAs window appears.

I know the way to convert via a Word object, but screenshots will not be printed and the header is missing. So, this is not an answer for me: [Save complete email, body and header, as PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69056935/save-complete-email-body-and-header-as-pdf/69075707#69075707)

How do I deal with the SaveAs dialog and the filename of the resulting pdf?

One possibility would be to print the mail to an xps file (print to file - how to do that). After that, I could convert xps to pdf using PDFSharp.

Comment: Ok, I managed to save it as a word document by MI.SaveAs(filename, olSaveAsType.olDoc) This document contains all the content and can be easily saved as a pdf.

Comment: There is no need to save it as a doc and then convert the saved file to a PDF one. Instead, use the Word object model from Outlook to get a PDF from the ground.

Answer (score 2):

The Word editor can be used for saving the message body as a PDF file.

```
Word.Document doc = mailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor;
doc.SaveAs2(fullPath, FileFormat: Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
```

Note, you need to add a COM reference to the Word object model to your project before using its object model in the code.